# Overfloating content

Tags: css, layout

I have an issue that wasn't visible in live share but when navigating my page in a gadget with touch-screen (in this case my Iphone-8 and tablet) Desktop seems ok.

The content is floating. Everything looks ok until I drag the content to the left or to the right, then a huge white space is visible in both sides.

I was using the bootstrap predefined container but I removed the link and the problem persists. (The link is commented out in this last commit). I also added a larger image for tablet view to test but it didnt help. I set the width for the containers to 100% as well and still.

Why this could be happening?

https://my-portfolio-dannuzak.netlify.app/

https://github.com/dannuzak/portfolio

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be because of 'div.social-media'.

[image]

You added 'left' to this and its width is '100%', which is the default for the div, so it will be wider than the screen by the value of 'left'.

A simple solution is to change the 'display' property of the '.social-media' class to 'inline-block'.

Answer (score 0):

because of you use `left` property in `".social-media"` div with `position:relative`, generally `left,top,right,bottom` use with `position:absoulte` or `postion:fixed`

```
.social-media {
  display: inline-block;
}
```